# Ordered broadcast for accepting incoming call not working

Tags: android

Im making an app that creates custom call receive screens. I've managed to show the screens and add a button for rejecting incoming call. For accepting incoming calls, my code isn't working. I'm trying to use ordered broadcasts for accepting the call but the code isn't working. Its not throwing any exceptions, or crashing. It just doesn't do anything. Here is the code I'm using:

```
Intent answer = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                answer.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
                sendOrderedBroadcast(answer, null);
```

I'm revising the old question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As the Exception message says, you lack the permission to answer phone calls.

Android uses a permissions system to guard an app's access to sensitive functionality. When you want to use certain functionality, you need to declare the permission to do that in your manifest.

There are two kinds of permissions: *normal* and *dangerous*. Normal ones are granted automatically if they are declared in the manifest. Dangerous ones additionally need runtime approval: Your app requests the declared permission at runtime and Android prompts the user for their approval. Read more about this [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

The permission you are looking for is [`Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS).

Declare it in your manifest like this:

```
<manifest […]>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS"/>
    <!-- declare other permissions the same way here -->

    […]

</manifest>
```

At runtime, check whether you have the required permission and only perform the action if you do:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity, Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // Your code using the dangerous permission goes here
} else {
    // request the permission, see below
}
```

Where `thisActivity` is your current Activity.

To request the permission, use:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[] {Manifest.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS},
            PERMISSIONS_ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS);
```

Where `PERMISSIONS_ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS` is an `int` constant you defined with a unique value.

The permission is requested asynchronously, meaning you will be notified when the permission is granted or denied. To receive this notification, override this callback:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode) { // check which permission was requested
        case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS:
            // check whether permission was granted
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted; you can call your method requiring this permission now
            } else {
                // permission was denied, you probably want to show a message that your feature won't be available
            }
            return;
            // code for other permission requests goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the permission in the manifest and requested it at runtime but that doesnt cut it. One thing i also dont get is why i would need ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS permission just to get a list of available media controllers cuz the exception comes at that point

Comment: You would need the `ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS` permission to actually answer phone calls. To get the list of available MediaControllers, you need to pass in the `ComponentName` of your enabled `NotificationListener`, see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager#getActiveSessions(android.content.ComponentName)

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "enabled"?